# Why isn't Google Analytics script loading in some browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, google-analytics

I use default generated GA tracking code for my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxx.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

This code seems to work in most cases. However, the _utm.gif is not requested from some browsers, (namely, I noticed it in Chromium on Ubuntu and Firefox on Fedora). Actually, it appears that the ga.js script is not even loaded.

If I use the GA Debugger or locally saved script ( `ga.src = 'ga.js';` ), the tracking works as expected even on mentioned browsers. Other tested OS-browser configurations works.

EDIT: As suggested in comments, I've tried to remove protocol resolution (i.e.: `ga.src =  'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js'`) and scripts other then ga.js (to rule out conflicts). It didn't change the behavior in any way.

Any ideas what causes the problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: Might it be that it is using `https`, and the browser is rejecting the certificate?

Comment: do you have other scripts that can create a conflict? are you loading this in the top head of your page?

Comment: jli: I think I've tried ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js' and it didn't work anyway.

Comment: lbu: The script is in the end of the head element as suggested by Google.

Comment: lbu: And yes. It is part of GWT application, so there are other scripts. I'll try it without them.

Comment: jli: I meant 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js' of course..

Comment: Ibu: I removed everything accept the GA script and it still behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the issue again today and everything appears to be working as it should.. I have no idea why..